# Activate specific tab after state change in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, ui-sref

I have a web app built in `AngularJS` where I use `$state` to navigate through my different `views`. I'm also using several [AngularUI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) components and styling, among other [Bootstrap tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs).

Now what I was wondering about is if there was some way to, combined with `ui-sref`, to activate a specific tab after you click on a link and the new `view` is loaded.

Ex.
I'm on the `Dashboard view` where there is a `link` that links directly to the second tab inside the `Test view`

**Dashboard html**

```
<div class="panel">
   <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4">Go to Test view and activate Image tab</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
       <a ui-sref="app.test({id: id})" class="btn btn-info">Test</a>
   </div>
</div
```

**Test html**

```
<tabset class="nav-tabs-alt" justified="true">
    <tab>
        <tab-heading>Information</tab-heading>
        <div class="Content">...</div>
    </tab>
    <tab>
        <tab-heading>Image</tab-heading>
        <div class="Content">...</div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: @charlietfl: Both tabs are in the same view / route. Sorry if I didn't explain it good enough..

Comment: ok..was just asking... have seen people try to use full tabs when all they need is tabs nav

Comment: definitely need to use `active` attribute...just not clear enough what relationship of route to tabs is

Comment: And that's more than fair :D and thanks for taking your time to look into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable to represent if a tab is active using the **active** attribute. In my code I am using a scope variable called `imageActive`.

```
 <tabset class="nav-tabs-alt" justified="true">
    <tab active="informationActive">
        <tab-heading>Information</tab-heading>
        <div class="Content">...</div>
    </tab>
    <tab active="imageActive">
        <tab-heading>Image</tab-heading>
        <div class="Content">...</div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Then make a link click set this variable appropriately, which will activate the 2nd tab:

```
 <a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="imageActive= true;">Test</a>
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that, so simple, but exactly what I needed. @James Lawruk: Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Backer Sure, no problem.